# Laravel 5.1 testing with model relationships and factories

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpunit, eloquent

Currently I have 2 models (and test factories) for:

- App\User
- App\Post

I've looked at the docs about test factories with relationships, but nothing is specifically shown for a single instance. What I have now is:

`$user = factory(App\User::class)->create();
$post = factory(App\Post::class)->create();
$post->user()->save($user);`

I'm currently getting the following PHPUnit error: `BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::save()`

I'm probably missing something small here. How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$post->user() returns relation definition, not the related object. If you need to associate user with the post and save it, you need to do the following:

```
$user = factory(App\User::class)->create();
$post = factory(App\Post::class)->create();
$post->user()->associate($user);
$post->save();
```